# PL/SQL developer v.10,how to disable autoreplace in Templates

Tags: plsqldeveloper

Not User Interface->Editor->AutoReplace.

I'm mean Templates,`$database` auto replace to `tnsname`:

```
select current_scn from v$database;
=>
select current_scn from vTEST_172.20.0.143;
```

---

How to google the question and what is keyword?

Comment: The software companies website has a support forum. You could also try to find an answer there: http://allroundautomations.com/

Comment: I think this is a very common question  /(ㄒoㄒ)/~~